# SQlite join row with multiple rows from other table(s)

Tags: sql, json, database, sqlite, join

I am using sqlite3 for storing data of my application. I need to perform a joined query on my database to receive combined information from multiple tables. The issue is, that I have to connect each row of `tbl_assets` with multiple rows from `tbl_users` and `tbl_permissions`.

I think the query result needs to be in a nested json format, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

To help you understand I posted a simplified example of my current **`database`**, **`query`**, **`result`** and **`desired_result`** below.

I have three tables in my **`database`**:

```
tbl_users
=========
id      | name
------------------
1       | user_1
2       | user_2
```

```
tbl_assets
==========
id      | title
------------------
3       | asset_1
4       | asset_2
```

```
tbl_permissions
===============
user_id | asset_id | can_read | can_edit | can_delete
------------------------------------------------------
1       | 3        | 1        | 1        | 0
1       | 4        | 1        | 1        | 1
2       | 4        | 1        | 1        | 1
```

I use the following **`query`** to retrieve data for user_1:

```
query = `
         SELECT a.*, p.can_read, p.can_edit, p.can_delete
         FROM tbl_users u
         INNER JOIN tbl_permissions p
         ON u.id = p.user_id
         INNER JOIN tbl_assets a
         ON a.id = p.asset_id
         WHERE u.id = '1'
        `
```

This returns user_1 a specific **`result`**:

```
result = [
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'asset_1',
    can_read: 1,
    can_edit: 1,
    can_delete: 0
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'asset_2',
    can_read: 1,
    can_edit: 1,
    can_delete: 1
  }
]
```

This is a good start, but not sufficient for my needs. In addition, I need to see in the results **all** users and their (specific) permissions on every asset returned. The following is an example of the **`desired_result`**:

```
desired_result = [
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'asset_1',
    permissions: [
                   {
                     user_id: 1
                     can_read: 1,
                     can_edit: 1,
                     can_delete: 0
                   }
                 ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'asset_2',
    permissions: [
                   {
                     user_id: 1
                     can_read: 1,
                     can_edit: 1,
                     can_delete: 1
                   },
                   {
                     user_id: 2
                     can_read: 1,
                     can_edit: 1,
                     can_delete: 1
                   }
                 ]
  }
]
```

I looked into certain options to achieve this, but I'm not sure which approach is best or would even be possible. **(!) Important: The result structure does not necessarily need to be exactly the same as in my example. The result only needs to contain the exact information as shown in the** `desired_result` **above.**

The following options came to my mind:

1. Modify my query -> Unfortunately I don't know how
2. Run an additional query on every asset in the `result` array -> poor performance when much data
3. Restructure my database -> Affects my code, seems to much effort

I would prefer to go with option 1. to modify my sql query to receive the result I desire in one query. My research did not lead me to a solution so far. I found something about "FOR JSON AUTO" in SQL Server, but that doesn't seem to work for sqlite. Pointing me in a direction would be very much appreciated.

If you **know** that my desired result cannot be achieved in one query I would appreciate a comment to stop searching for solutions in that direction.

If restructuring my database would be a good suggestion I would appreciate an example structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need aggregation with SQLite's [JSON Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT a.*, 
         json_group_array(
           json_object(
             'user_id', u.id, 
             'can_read', p.can_read, 
             'can_edit', p.can_edit, 
             'can_delete', p.can_delete
           )
         ) permissions
  FROM tbl_assets a
  INNER JOIN tbl_permissions p ON a.id = p.asset_id
  INNER JOIN tbl_users u ON u.id = p.user_id
  GROUP BY a.id
)
SELECT json_group_array(
         json_object(
           'id', id,
           'title', title,
           'permissions', permissions
         ) 
       ) desired_result
FROM cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/e9IGG4gW).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much! Just for the record, why did you pick 'cte' as abbreviation?

Comment: @maxischl it derives from [common table expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html). You can use any valid name that you want.